# Page width wider than viewport, blank space to the right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The width of my page is too long to the right. I don't know what is making it unsymmetrical. It probably is the many "position:relative"s that I put on it in order to make things beautiful and aligned since I'm not a masted of coding to do it any other way.

Here's how it looks like to me:

[Print1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjBnx.png)
[Print2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Obhrj.png)

Here are my codes:

```js
<script src="jQueryUI/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryUI/jquery-ui.css"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
 $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
  axis: 'x', containment: [-234,0,450,0]
 });
});
</script>

<script>
$( "*", document.body ).click(function( event ) {
  var offset = $( "#circle" ).offset();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var conta = (offset.left - 752)/3.42;
  var posFinal = Math.round( conta );
  $( "#luc" ).text( posFinal + "%" );
});
  </script>
```

```css
.draggable {
 width: 700px;
 height: 0px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 position: relative;
}

#bar {
 width: 350px;
 height: 12px;
 background-color: #ff0a00;
 border-right: 350px solid #00b4ff;
 margin: 0px auto;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#circle {
 position: relative;
 top: -15px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

#discordo {
 position: relative;
 top: 65px;
 left: -386px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#concordo {
 position: relative;
 top: 31.8px;
 left: 390px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#organizado {
 position: relative;
 top: -70px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="x.php" id="questions">
<h3>Pergunta 1</h3>
<p>Maconha deveria ser legalizada para uso recreacional</p>
<div id="organizado">
<p id="discordo">Discordo</p>
<p id="concordo">Concordo</p>
<div id="bar"> </div>
<div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
<div id="circle"> </div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
<p id="luc"></p>
```

Comment: You are overusing `position: relative`. Use it sparsely only when needed. You will run into even more problems if you don't.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough html and css code to determine whats causing this, however try adding `overflow-x:hidden` to the whole document by putting the following in your css file:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box. Setting it to hidden will clip all that excess space and make it invisible. 
`overflow-x` will stop you from being able to scroll horizontally